# how partition reader from database, writer in different files and optimize thread load

Tags: spring-batch

EDIT:

I think that there are something wrong with this clause:

I tried to run my first test that runs single thread and take about 35 minutes with this whereCause and the execution is terribly slow. When I just do an select * from table, whitout whereClause the process happens normally.

---

I trying to use Step Partitioning in a Job with Spring Batch, but I dont realize if is it's 
appropriate to my case:

I have read from a database with ~30 million records. In the record, I have a column bank_id and there is about 23 differents banks.

I have to read the value from this column and separate the records from each bank into different txt files.

I want my job parallelize the work in 4 or 8 threads, in a first moment I try to use step partitioning and I split the job in 4 slaves and set the id_bank that I process in a parameter for a query in SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean and I use only 4 different Ids. But the amount of records from one bank_id to another varies widely resulting in a slave finish they job before anothers.

I want that when the slave finish they work, he begin to process another bank_id.

I need a help to do anything like this in spring batch. I use the 2.1 version of spring batch.

here is my files:

```
<bean id="arquivoWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names"
                            value="name_bank, id_bank, etc" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="format"
                    value="..." />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="resource"
            value="file:./arquivos/#{stepExecutionContext[faixa]}.txt" />
    </bean>



<job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep"> 
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <handler task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="pagingReader" writer="arquivoWriter"
            commit-interval="#{jobParameters['commit.interval']}" />

        <listeners>
            <listener ref="myChunkListener"></listener>
        </listeners>        
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="....RangePartitioner" />



<bean id="pagingReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="fetchSize" value="#{jobParameters['fetch.size']}"></property>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                       SELECT ...
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM my_table" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="where id_bank = :id_op" /> 

        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="id_op" value="#{stepExecutionContext[id_op]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="maxItemCount" value="#{jobParameters['max.rows']}"></property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="....reader.MyRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

The range partitioner:

```
public class RangePartitioner implements Partitioner {

@Autowired
BancoDao bancoDao;

final Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext> ();
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    List<OrgaoPagadorQuantidadeRegistrosTO> lista = bancoDao.findIdsOps();
    for (OrgaoPagadorQuantidadeRegistrosTO op:lista){
        String name = String.valueOf(op.getIdOrgaoPagador());
        ExecutionContext ex = new ExecutionContext();
        ex.putLong("id_op", op.getIdBank());
        ex.putString ("faixa", name);
        result.put("p"+name, ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for should work assuming that you have enough work for each of the slaves to work on.  For example, if you have 23 banks but one has 20 million records and the others each have 100,000, the slaves not working on the big bank will free up quickly.

Are you creating a StepExecution per bank or per thread?  I'd recommend doing it per bank.  This would allow threads to pick up work as they finish.  Otherwise, you end up being responsible for that load balancing by implementing a Partitioner that does this normalization.

Comment: One StepExecution per bank, there are 4 banks with ~ 6m, in others there are much less. Now I succeed to execute with Partition, but all the process take 8 hours to finish (with sequencial single thread I got a time of 40 minutes). I'm using 4 threads working at same time, the bottleneck occurs when the data is written to disk. The writer I'm using is almost same the other I use in single thread, the difference is that I create one instance per file (bank) when I do the partition.

Comment: What writer are you using and how is it configured?

Comment: Hello Michael, I appended the context configuration and the range partitioner to the original message.

Comment: now I got whats is wrong. I have index the id_bank column on the database, but I in the keySort I chose another column, this slow down the query.